# How to use IF loop in XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have an framework which takes inputs from XML and runs the test . 
Depending on an parameters which is been sent into XML some tests will be decided to Run or Not .

For checking this condition,I need to apply  ***IF loop***

How to apply IF loop in XML ( I don't want to use XSLT ) . Or is there any method to check condition ?

Comment: XML is **data**. Data ins't logic. If you do not want to transform the data (XSLT, for example) then your "framework" has to interpret that XML and check for those conditions (it might be an attribute `condition` or a full node `<if>`, for example)

Comment: Show us a sample xml and your framework (tech used to parse XML) and state the actual problem.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 0):

XML is a data format, not a programming language.

To read or write XML, use a programming language, preferably with an XML library.  Reading XML is best done with an XML parser.

It is in the programming language where the concepts of conditionals and iteration such as `if` and `loop` apply.

Note finally that some programming languages such as XSLT use XML as their syntax.  Ant uses XML as its syntax for expressing build dependencies and processes.  Still, here you'd not ask how to use `if` and `loop` in XML but rather in XSLT or Ant or whatever programming language is leveraging XML as its syntax.